# Identify PCB component from LED circuit

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I'm trying to refurb a old pcb taken from a 30 year old cars indicator unit, it's a pretty simple pcb besides one component I'm unable to identify:

[image: component1]

[image: component2]

You can see it attached to the back here before I took it out and cleaned it up

[image: component3]

Anyone know what this is and where I could source a replacement?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Pictures of the back:

Before I started to clean it up:

[image: before cleanup]

After:

[image: back1]
[image: back2]

Comment: Can you draw a schematic? Or clean the pcb and show a picture form the other side? It looks to me like a normal diode bridge.

Comment: Added pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bridge rectifier but I can't think why there would be one in a 12 V DC circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVzNx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A bridge rectifier consists of four diodes.*

There's no scale reference in your photo but I'd guess that's a 1 A device and so is unlikely to be in the actual indicator lamp circuit as these are normally 21 W lamps drawing nearly 2 A each when hot and a lot more when the filament is cold. It's more likely to be rectifying the power for the flasher unit itself.

They're available from any electronics component supplier. You'll find a parameterised search on any of the large suppliers. Select something that's rated for 50 V and whatever current you think is required.

Comment: It would make the indicator polarity insensitive.

Comment: probably not 21W through those LEDs

Comment: As that most likely goes to a standard bulb holder, the bulbs are symmetric and have no polarity. So uglyoldbob is right that this enables the LED bulbs to be used in any orientation and they will light up just like normal bulbs. So including a bridge rectifier does make sense a lot.

Comment: There's only two visible wires and there are two different colours of LED. Could it be steering current to one colour or the other based on the polarity?

Comment: The LEDS are all the same, it's just some of them are rusted beyond recognition

Comment: There may be some confusion here. In Ireland / UK "indicator unit" would imply "turn signal" and I read the question as being about those or the flasher controller. Could you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Yes it is a turn signal but it's not the LED's that change the colour its the casing: https://i.imgur.com/PQ4N3ru.jpg The car is a 30 year old japanese import, I believe as 'Justme' pointed out this pcb is to allow LED's to replace what would have been a single candescent bulb.

Comment: "Surface discolouration" :-)